# Is it possible to have a sub within a sub?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to have a sub within a sub?

```
Public Class Form1

     Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
         Sub anim() Handles form2.Shown

             Me.Refresh()

             Do Until Me.Location.X = 350
                 form2.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X + 1, 250)
                 ' System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0.5)
             Loop
                form2.close()
         End Sub
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim form2 As New Form2()

    Dim anim = Sub()
                   form2.Refresh()
                   Do Until form2.Location.X = 350
                       form2.Location = New Point(form2.Location.X + 1, 250)
                       ' System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0.5)
                   Loop

               End Sub

    AddHandler form2.Shown, anim
    form2.Show()
End Sub
```